# Mismatched types error while deserializing with pattern matching

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, deserialization

I'm attempting to deserialize a csv value into a different type of struct based on a value passed into a function.

I am not understanding why I am receiving a `mismatched types` error. Why does it find struct `CitiRec` when it lives in a different match arm?

```
pub fn get_uncat_rec(path: &PathBuf, bank_type: BankType) -> Vec<UnCatRecord> {
  let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_path(path).unwrap();
  let mut uncat_rec: Vec<UnCatRecord> = Vec::new();

  for record in reader.deserialize() {
    match bank_type {
      BankType::Citi => {
        let rec_result: Result<CitiRec, csv::Error> = record;
        match rec_result {
          Ok(rec_result) => {
            uncat_rec.push(rec_result.to_uncat_rec());
          }
          Err(err) => {
            println!("Error received deserializing Citi Record: {}", err);
          }
        }
      }
      BankType::Kasaka => {
        let rec_result: Result<KasakaRec, csv::Error> = record; <-- **error here**
        match rec_result {
          Ok(rec_result) => {
            uncat_rec.push(rec_result.to_uncat_rec());
          }
          Err(err) => {
            println!("Error received deserializing Kasaka Record: {}", err);
          }
        }
      }
      _ => {}
    }
```

Here is the error that receive:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  --> src\normalizer.rs:26:57
   |
26 |         let rec_result: Result<KasakaRec, csv::Error> = record;
   |                         -----------------------------   ^^^^^^ expected struct `KasakaRec`, found struct `CitiRec`
   |                         |
   |                         expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<KasakaRec, _>`
              found enum `Result<CitiRec, _>`
```

Comment: This code is not reproducible. Please give us at least all the types involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type cannot be conditional. `record` has one, and exactly one, type.

From the first `match` arm the compiler is concluding that you're deserializing into `CitiRec`s. But in the second it appears that you are deserializing into `KasakaRec`s, and this is a conflict.

A way to solve that is to have a separate loop for each arm, so we can deserialize to different types:

```rust
pub fn get_uncat_rec(path: &PathBuf, bank_type: BankType) -> Vec<UnCatRecord> {
    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_path(path).unwrap();
    let mut uncat_rec: Vec<UnCatRecord> = Vec::new();

    match bank_type {
        BankType::Citi => {
            for record in reader.deserialize() {
                let rec_result: Result<CitiRec, csv::Error> = record;
                match rec_result {
                    Ok(rec_result) => {
                        uncat_rec.push(rec_result.to_uncat_rec());
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("Error received deserializing Citi Record: {}", err);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        BankType::Kasaka => {
            for record in reader.deserialize() {
                let rec_result: Result<KasakaRec, csv::Error> = record;
                match rec_result {
                    Ok(rec_result) => {
                        uncat_rec.push(rec_result.to_uncat_rec());
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("Error received deserializing Kasaka Record: {}", err);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you. It still feels weird that the compiler can't assume those arms are independent. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about matching on enums.

Comment: @ZachW No, you are misunderstanding something about types. Each variable has only one type. This is required for code generation, for stack size calculation and more.

Comment: Okay. That tracks a little better. Thank you.